# Multiple access points with single SSID, unable to roam from one to the other

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have four access points at home all of them wired to a non-intelligent switch which is also wired to the internet access router. The DHCP and NAT service is provided by the Internet access router and all AP function perfectly well independently. All AP are configured with the same SSID, same security setting WPA2 (Personal). In short if you start up the system portable devices will work anywhere in the house. However if I try to move from AP to AP although the device will connect to the new AP it will not get a new IP address and will therefore be unable to connect to the network. If I reset the central non-configurable switch the device will connect perfectly to the new AP but will now not be able to go back the original one.

I have also tried another, configurable, switch both in Router and Gateway modes, enabling and disabling RIP but to no avail.

Comment: It shouldn't get a new IP address. It should keep its existing IP address. The lease is still valid, it still has the same hardware address, and it's still connected to the same network.

Comment: When you tried the other switch, did you have the exact same problem? I think this problem is caused by your switch not clearing the dynamic entry to the first AP's port when it receives a packet on the second AP's port. That's broken behavior seen in some cheap switches. If you had a *different* problem with the other switch, that would suggest *this* problem may well be caused by *this* switch.

Comment: Thanks David, I will install the other *intelligent* switch again to check the symptoms, however as far as I remember they were identical.